# How to extend an Operator

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

I tried to extend my own Operator but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

If I add this operator I get "Test"

```
class OperatorX(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "test.x"
bl_label = "Test X"

strprop = bpy.props.StringProperty(default = "Test")

def execute(self, context):
    print(self.strprop)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Then I add the next operator extends the first.

```
class OperatorY(OperatorX):
bl_idname = "test.y"
bl_label = "Test Y"

def execute(self, context):
    print(self.strprop)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

If I call OperatorX I get:

```
bpy_class_call: unable to get python class for rna struct 'TEST_OT_x'
```

And if I call OperatorY I get:

```
(<built-in function StringProperty>, {'attr': 'strprop', 'default': 'Test'})
```

I need a few operators with the same properties but different execution.
How to solve it?

Florian

Comment: Related  [class mix in example](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_overview.html#integration-through-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@batFINGER: Thank you! It works.

I've done it like this now:

```
import bpy

class Base:
    strprop = bpy.props.StringProperty(default = "Test")

class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator, Base):
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.strprop)
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)
```

Comment: That's the one. Small heads up, need to follow the naming convention eg `OBJECT_OT_my_operator` [in 2.8](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/Source/Python/UpdatingScripts)